# Detect Ethernet cable connection

Tags: design, ethernet

I would like to know if it possible to detect the connection of an ethernet cable when it is connected to my PCB. Ideally I would like to implement a circuit that signals to my SOM that the ethernet cable has been connected so that the SOM can turn on the ethernet hardware. The reason for this is that we are having EMC issues with the ethernet hardware and thus are trying to minimize when it is used.

Are there any circuits out there that can detect the connection of an ethernet cable without affecting signal integrity?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If there is, it would be more likely to be easier to just solve the EMC issues than to work around them by designing even more complex hardware to detect link pulses without disturbing the signal.

Comment: Does your compliance test oblige that the Ethernet is connected? I assume that would be the case. So one way or another you need to work on your magnetics, perhaps upgrading to type that includes EMI suppression.

Comment: You need to fix "EMC issues with the Ethernet hardware" anyway. It is well know area of work. Try to configure the system to Wake-on-LAN (WoL) and see if the MAC (assume that is the noise source) goes into less power mode (some MAC chip does filtering of WoL). Otherwise, I don't know sure (search on the web) but you need to build a detection circuitry around (likely right behind) the magnetics. It shouldn't be so difficult.